# how to tell ccxt to use binance / bybit testnet

Tags: python, binance, ccxt

i wrote a small script to download ohlcv data from binance or bybit with ccxt.
I want to get candle data from the testnet as well as the main net.
I looked at ccxt code and there are urls for both nets, yet i do not know
how to set the option.

I guess there has to be something like.
bybitt = ccxt.binance({ 'option': { 'defaultMarket': 'future' }})

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 17):

With CCXT you can switch to the sandbox/testnet if the underlying exchange has it, using the `.set_sandbox_mode` method like so:

```
import ccxt
exchange = ccxt.binance({'enableRateLimit': True})
exchange.set_sandbox_mode(True)
```

- https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/python/ccxt/base/exchange.py#L1433
- https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/python/ccxt/binance.py#L88
- https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/python/ccxt/bybit.py#L72

Comment: I can read my balances using ccxt and my API keys, now I set sandbox_mode and it's not working anymore

Comment: @DenCowboy paste your version numbers, your code and most importantly your verbose output as explained here: https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/wiki/FAQ#what-is-required-to-get-help

Comment: Make sure you don't confuse the testnet API keys with the exchange's production API keys.

Comment: @DenCowboy because you need to use different API keys for sandbox and normal mode